# MySQL: Cumulative sum of column A and column B into Column B

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sample data. [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ixi837k1z0ysvr/cumulative%20sum%20of%20columns%20as%20per%20date%2C%20floor%20and%20time.xlsx?dl=0)
I need to get the cumulative sum of column **abc-xyz** and **reqdcolumn** per date, hour, shop. 
My mysql version is 5.7 Row over solution doesn't work for my mysql version.

Sample data

```
date      hour  Shop       abc     xyz  Diffabcxyz  ReqdColumn
---------------------------------------------------------------
20190428    1       1       0       0       0           0
20190428    2       1       5       4       1           0
20190428    3       1       15      8       7           1
20190428    4       1       16      9       7           8
20190428    5       1       14      13      1           15
20190428    6       1       8       12      -4          16
20190428    7       1       14      16      -2          12
20190428    8       1       9       7       2           10
20190428    9       1       5       2       3           12
20190428    10      1       6       2       4           15
20190428    1       2       0       0       0           0
20190428    2       2       7       1       6           0
20190428    3       2       5       -2      3           6
20190428    4       2       6       -5      1           9
20190428    5       2       4       7       -3          10
20190428    6       2       5       -8      -3          7
20190428    7       2       2       -9      -7          4
20190428    8       2       9       -10     -1          -3
20190428    9       2       6       4       2           -4
20190428    10      2       2       -12     -10         -2
20190428    1       3       0       0       0           0
20190428    2       3       6       -11     -5          0
20190428    3       3       8       -4      4           -5
20190428    4       3       5       -5      0           -1
20190428    5       3       9       8       1           -1
20190428    6       3       2       -1      1           0
20190428    7       3       4       4       0           1
20190428    8       3       1       2       -1          1
20190428    9       3       11      -4      7           0
20190428    10      3       0       1       -1          7
```

I tried to do a cumulative sum but didn't know how to group by the result set.

Tested codes:

Testing select

```
set @csum := 0;

SELECT 
    date, hour, shop, (@csum:=@csum + Diffabcxyz)
FROM
    SampleTable
GROUP BY date, hour, shop;
```

testing update

```
set @csum := 0;
update sampletable
set reqdcolumn = (@csum := @csum + Diffabcxyz);
```

I need to group by the result set with date, time and shop.

Sample data and required result are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ixi837k1z0ysvr/cumulative%20sum%20of%20columns%20as%20per%20date%2C%20floor%20and%20time.xlsx?dl=0). **ReqdColumn** is the desired output

Comment: You can't really expect users to go to dropbox to look at your data. Please post a sample in your question.

Comment: Nick, sorry added the sample data with desired column at the end

Comment: I'm confused, shouldn't the cumulative sum values happen one row earlier? Otherwise you miss the last value of `Diffabcxyz` for a shop

Comment: Also, should the cumulative sum reset when a new day starts?

Comment: the 1st hour will always have 0 value in cumulative sum. after data analysis, this is the algorithm I need to implement.

YES, it need to reset every day at the 1st hour in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve SQL Server `LAG` functionalisty in order to get that cumulative sum:

```
select @lagDate := 0, @lagShop := 0, @diffLag := 0, @cumSum := 0;

select *,
       case when @lagDate = Date and @lagShop = Shop then @cumSum := @cumSum + @diffLag else @cumSum := 0 end,
       @diffLag := Diffabcxyz,
       @lagDate := Date,
       @lagShop := Shop
from tbl
order by shop, date, hour
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vqN6NaHnpMRsLnhJxAnt3x/0)

UPDATE regarding comment:

> Can you please tell me how can i get it to not do the cumulative count for the first 3 hours?

```
select @lagDate := 0, @lagShop := 0, @diffLag := 0, @cumSum := 0, @diffLagLag := 0;

select *,
       case when @lagDate = Date and @lagShop = Shop then @cumSum := @cumSum + @diffLagLag else @cumSum := 0 end,
       @diffLagLag := @diffLag,
       @diffLag := Diffabcxyz,
       @lagDate := Date,
       @lagShop := Shop
from tbl
order by shop, date, hour
```

[Another demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vqN6NaHnpMRsLnhJxAnt3x/1)

ANOTHER UPDATE:

```
select @lagDate := 0, @lagShop := 0, @diffLag := 0, @cumSum := 0;

select *,
       case when @lagDate = Date and @lagShop = Shop and Hour > 3 then @cumSum := @cumSum + @diffLag else @cumSum := 0 end,
       @diffLag := Diffabcxyz,
       @lagDate := Date,
       @lagShop := Shop
from tbl
order by shop, date, hour
```

[Yet another demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vqN6NaHnpMRsLnhJxAnt3x/2)

Comment: Hey Michal, Your code is working. Thanks very much.
It resets the 1st hour to 0, Can you please tell me how can i get it to not do the cumulative count for the first 3 hours? i.e. 0 for hour 1,2 and 3. and then start cumulative sum from the 4th hour for every date, hour, shop like in your solution above?

Comment: I need this new logic as my data for the 1st 3 hours give negative value and my requirement is to now start at 4th hour of each day for cumulative sum.

Comment: thanks for your response.
how can I achieve 1st, 2nd and 3rd hour of every day per shop = 0
From 4th hour, get cumulative value. for the 4th-hour by using the value of the 3rd hour, not 1st.
Also, from your query for the 2nd shop, cumulative sum starts from 2nd hour.

Comment: sorry if my question is too confusing. Let me know i will link a google sheet with more explaination if required.

Comment: @SuccessMaharjan . . . MySQL *expressly* states that the order of evaluation of expressions is not guaranteed in `SELECT` statements:  "the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined."  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).  This is not a good answer, because it relies on behavior that is explicitly documented not to work.